# DevStack across reboot

Tags: openstack

I'd like to know how to make DevStack persistent and work across reboot.

I know some service do not automatically start since it's not made for production use.
But I'd like to be able to do stuff on the VM I have DevStack running in, shut it down, and when I get back to it be presented with the same state I had before shutting down the VM.

```
./rejoin_stack.sh
```

is not sufficient by itself, I keep getting a `401 Unauthorized` page presented.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? If so please post some more details about your issue.